# creating pivot table in sql filled with 1 and 0

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have table1 which contains ids [s1,s2,s3..Sn]

```
s1
s2
s3
```

I have another table2 containing indexes [0,1,2,..n].

```
0
1
2
3
```

I have third table3 [ids, start_index,stop_index]. eg:

```
s0 | 1 | 3 | 
s0 | 4 | 6 | 
s1 | 1 | 2 |
```

and so on. I want to create a pivot table which contains rows a s1,s2,s3... columns with 0,1,2,3.. content of the table should be either zero or 1.

```
---|0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |...
s0 |0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
s1 |0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
.
.
```

Comment: You've tagged 2 very different RDBMS; which are you actually using? I've removed the conflicting tags, please retag the correct one, and *only* the corrrect one. What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **CROSS JOIN** in concert with your index table and **PIVOT** the final results.

If you number of columns is variable, you would need DYNAMIC SQL

**Example**

```
 Select *
  From  (
        Select id 
              ,item = a.[index]
              ,value = case when a.[index] between b.start_index and b.stop_index then 1 else 0 end
          From  table2  A
          Cross Join table3 B 
        )  src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: I *think* `table2` is (effectively) their tally table.

Comment: @Larnu On second look, you are correct.  I'll make the adjustment